# Make a file look not messed up

Tags: bash, delimiter

I have a file that looks messed up:

```
contig_1  bin.0013 Rhizobium           flavum    (taxid 1335061)
contig_2           Alphaproteobacteria (taxid    28211)
contig_3  bin.009
contig_4  bin.008  unclassified        (taxid    0)
contig_5  bin.001  Fluviicoccus        keumensis (taxid 1435465)
contig_12 bin.003
```

I want it to look properly with tab delimited columns and zeros where it's empty:

```
contig_1    bin.0013    Rhizobium flavum (taxid 1335061)
contig_2    0           Alphaproteobacteria (taxid 28211)
contig_3    bin.009     0
contig_4    bin.008     unclassified (taxid 0)
contig_5    bin.001     Fluviicoccus keumensis (taxid 1435465)
contig_12   bin.003     0
```

If I use smth like `sed 's/  /,/g' filename` commas are inserted everywhere besides 1-2 and 2-3 columns.

Comment: try `column` command

Comment: I tried and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: This is not as simple as you think. Looking at your first file, I would have assumed there should be 5 fields (`config_1`, `bin.0013`, `Rhizobium`, `flavum`, `(tax id ...)`). Yet it turns out there are only 3.

Comment: yes, this comes from the input file with names like `Rhizobium flavum (taxid 1335061)` with spaces. Though I hope there should be a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
NR==FNR {
    # in the 1st pass, detect the starting positions of the 2nd field and the 3rd
    sub(" +$", "")      # it avoids misdetection due to extra trailing blanks
    if (match($0, "[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+")) {
        # RLENGTH holds the ending position of the 1st blank
        if (col2 == 0 || RLENGTH < col2) col2 = RLENGTH + 1
        if (match($0, "[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+")) {
            # RLENGTH holds the ending position of the 2nd blank
            if (col3 == 0 || RLENGTH < col3) col3 = RLENGTH + 1
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    # in the 2nd pass, extract the substrings in the fixed position and reformat them
    # by removing extra spaces and putting "0" if the fiels is empty
    c1 = substr($0, 1, col2 - 1); sub(" +$", "", c1); if (c1 == "") c1 = "0"
    c2 = substr($0, col2, col3 - col2); sub(" +$", "", c2); if (c2 == "") c2 = "0"
    c3 = substr($0, col3); gsub(" +", " ", c3); if (c3 == "") c3 = "0"
#   print c1, c2, c3            # use this for the tab-separated output
    printf("%-12s%-12s%-s\n", c1, c2, c3)
}' file file
```

Output:

```
contig_1    bin.0013    Rhizobium flavum (taxid 1335061)
contig_2    0           Alphaproteobacteria (taxid 28211)
contig_3    bin.009     0
contig_4    bin.008     unclassified (taxid 0)
contig_5    bin.001     Fluviicoccus keumensis (taxid 1435465)
contig_12   bin.003     0
```

- The process consists of two passes. In the 1st pass, it detects the starting positions of the fields.
- In the 2nd pass, it cuts out individual fields by using the positions calculated in the 1st pass.
- I have picked `printf` to visually align the output. You can switch to `tab separated values`
  depending on the preference.